# Memory Management BSOD, memtest shows no errors

Tags: windows-10, memory, bsod

My Windows 10 (updated regular) started to drop BSOD on me in the last week - 3 on Saturday  3rd and 2 today (also Saturday 10th, derp). 4 of them were MEMORY_MANAGEMENT and one PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA. The latter happened also one time in January, and the January one was the first BSOD this PC had since the OS installation iirc back in late 2020/beginning of 2021. Didn't change anything hardware wise (last hardware change [adding 2nd SSDs drive] came with the OS installation), no new drivers (MOBO drivers are last available from Gigabyte, didn't install drivers with WinUpdate, only OS updates), Nvidia GPU drivers also from the OS installation time as I didn't had to update them (don't really play games or use GPU heavy stuff lately)

The first 3 MEMORY_MANAGEMENT that happened last Saturday: 1st while working in Firefox when a tab crashed and then closing FFx dropped BSOD, 2nd after reboot by opening Firefox and the 3rd after reboot by opening Opera. (reboots by Windows after BSOD, didn't manual reset Windows after each BSOD reboot)

Due to the MEMORY_MANAGEMENT error I went and booted memtest86 (v.4.3.7) and did full scans of my memory sticks. I have 4x 8GBs (Goodram, all same models/speed/etc, 1st pair bought in 2013, 2nd pair bought in 2016/2017). Results:

- 1st run 4 sticks - 2 errors on TEST 7 (sadly didn't take a photo :/ , but weird part is that when I look at memtest error images on the net they are all red but my wasn't)
- each stick separately - no errors (each stick 4-5 passes of all available tests)
- 2nd run 4 sticks - no errors (4 passes)

I was kind of surprised that memtest was showing that each 8GB stick had 7.6GBs of memory so after googling I checked my BIOS and disabled Intel GPU and redid all the test again:

- 1st run 4 sticks - no errors (2 passes)
- each stick separately - no errors (each stick 4 passes)
- 2nd run 4 sticks - no errors (2 passes)

I also used Ultimate Boot CD and used memtest v5 from it (did just 2 passes on all 4 sticks, no errors) and the Windows Memory Diagnostics v0.4 (again all 4 sticks, 2 passes with extended test, no errors).

After all those tests I booted my PC at Thursday, it worked for like 2 hours, Firefox all the time open - everything worked fine. Booted today - it worked for like 7-8 hours and only after that amount of time FFx again crashed one tab and this resulted in a BSOD (with MEMORY_MANAGEMENT), after reboot the PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA happened while closing Excel. After this I closed my PC.

Specs: i7-4700, Gigabyte GA-Z97-D3H, GTX 770.

What can I do to find what is happening with my PC?

Comment: Hello, Do you have any minidump files you can share.  They should be under `\windows\minidump\`.

Comment: Have you done these things? Could be disk problem affecting page file- did you try `chkdsk /f /r` and then `sfc /scannow` in a Administrator cmd prompt? Also set a custom page file size, if virtual memory is set to Automatically manage paging files for all drives’. It might also be useful to check Windows updates and drivers as they are often the cause of Page Fault In Nonpaged Area errors.

Comment: @HelpingHand https://we.tl/t-2SD3Sy6aRc - minidumps that I copied last week (don't have todays ones)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey didn't try any chkdsk/sfc as I wanted to firstly exclude hardware problems so that I won't get more BSOD while doing anything on the OS (be it updates or the cmd commands). If I remember I didn't touch page file setting (so it's set to default) but I never need additional ram (this PC was used by brother for video editing so he used most of the ram, when I took it I changed drives and I barely go above 10GBs of used RAM). I also checked CrystalDiskInfo all everything was ok with the drives.

Comment: @Bob - Post only the relevant information from the analyst output from WinDBG as an edit to your question.

Comment: It does seem to relate to process exit, be it Firefox or Opera in the case of the shared dump files. If you close all Firefox processes, launch Firefox and close it down, does it always bugcheck as the process exits?  I'd be curious to know if the same happens in Safe Mode with networking if that is the case.

Comment: Disk is hardware, no?

Comment: @HelpingHand - didn't try as after the bsod-reboot opening Firefox/Opera/Excel ends in a BSOD so I can't open/close processes/open again. But in case of Firefox it seems to only bsod after it encounters an error on the current active tab and crashes the tab (with something like this https://assets-prod.sumo.prod.webservices.mozgcp.net/media/uploads/images/2018-11-26-13-43-00-d335b3.png [taken from mozzila support]). But if there are no tab crashes it closes normally without a bsod (as it was at Thursday).

Comment: @Ramhound - I never used WinDBG, what are the "relevant information" after opening a crashdump file and doing the !analyze -v as suggested by the application? (it's a total of 151 lines of info after copying it into notepad)?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Yes, you got me here :) I meant any other non-disk hardware, mostly ram as the MEMORY_MANAGEMENT suggested to me that the issues is ram related. I try now to gather info what to check and will try to do stuff in the following days so I will also check the disk. Should I check all of them (1st os ssd, 2nd ssd, 3rd hdd) or just concentrate on the OS ssd?

Comment: @Bob - There lots of existing questions with answers that explain how to use WinDBG, so you’ll need to use that information, to generate the analysis and provide the relevant information from the output